# Python program loop issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I am doing a Python program. My task is to ask the user to enter payroll information for a company. Set up a loop that continues to ask for information until the user enters "DONE". For each employee ask three questions:

1. first and last name
2. hours worked this week (only allow 1 - 60)
3. hourly wage (only allow 6.00 - 20.00)

Here is my code:

```
while True: #initiate loop
    strNames = input("Enter the employee's first and last name:")
    strHours = input("Enter total number of hours worked this week:")
    strWage = input("Enter employee's hourly wage:")
    if strNames =="DONE":
        break #breaks loop
    else:
        if strHours < "1" or strHours > "60":
            print("Error")
        if strWage < "6" or strWage > "20":
            print("Error")
```

When I run the program and enter the information, it prints:

> "Error Enter the employee's first and last name:"

Can anyone help me/guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You've compared strings, rather than numeric values.  Since `"20" < "6"`, *every* string will fulfill one of your two conditions and print `Error`.

1. Review your class materials; learn to recognize the appropriate data type for an application, and work with that data type.  In this case, you need to convert the input to `int` and work with numeric values.
2. Practice incremental programming: get a few lines working before you add more.  In this example, you've gone two steps past the working code, which complicates your debugging.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the previous post you cannot compare strings. What you can do is cast them as integers and then do the comparison.

The last requirement

> Set up a loop that continues to ask for information until the user enters "DONE"

You are only doing this once in you application after the user answers all the questions. I am not sure if you intended for this? If you would prefer the user to have the ability to exit the application at any point you could re-factor your code as I did so below

```
questions = ["Enter the employee's first and last name:",
             "Enter total number of hours worked this week:",
             "Enter employee's hourly wage:"]
var = ['strNames', 'strHours', 'strWage']
while True: #initiate loop
    x = 0 # declare a variable for incrementing list 'var'
    for q in questions:
        var[x] = input(q)
        if var[x].upper() =="DONE": # checking if the user entered 'DONE' 
            break # breaks inner for loop
        x += 1 # increment list count by 1 
    try:
        if int(var[1]) < 1 or int(var[1]) > 60:
            print("\n>>> Hours worked this week error\n")
        if int(var[2]) < 6 or int(var[2]) > 20:
            print("\n>>> Hourly wage error\n")
    except: # catches any exception errors
        # if exception occurs, come in here and break out of loop
        break # break while loop
```

Comments added to the above code, so please read for clarification.

Answer (score -1):

```
while True: #initiate loop
    strNames = input("Enter the employee's first and last name: ")
    if strNames =="DONE":
        break #breaks loop

    strHours = int(input("Enter total number of hours worked this week: "))
    if strHours < 1 or strHours > 60:
        print("Error 1")
        break

    strWage = int(input("Enter employee's hourly wage: "))
    if strWage < 6 or strWage > 20:
        print("Error 2")
        break

    if strNames =="DONE":
        break #breaks loop
```

Comment: I have stuck to your code as much as possible, but have changed the order of the statements. In this form the program works fine.
Also, the loop will end if you input "DONE" in response to 
"Enter the employee's first and last name:"